# 60's-70's Sci-Fi anthology(?) - planet Earth is overly hot and in the end the sun explodes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I was in the third grade and happened across this (1993-94'), but never read the whole thing.

I believe the planet was very hot due to issues with the sun possibly. I know the ending goes along the lines of the boy runs outside, kisses a girl, and just then the sun exploded?

I have come to believe it was in a sci-fi short story anthology, small paperback. I believe it to have been older maybe 60's-70's.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember? For example: when were you in third grade?

Comment: "[Disaster Area's] songs are on the whole very simple and mostly follow the familiar theme of boy-being meets girl-being beneath a silvery moon, which then explodes for no adequately explored reason."

Comment: @Wruy: [*The Year of the Jackpot*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year_of_the_Jackpot) ends with a man and woman embracing and then waiting for the sun to explode.  Maybe that's the story you have in mind.

Answer (score 8):

I think this story is called "The Wind from the Sun" (not the Arthur C. Clarke story), and the book is called [*Out of This World: Tales of Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?416436+c) (1983) by Allan Graubard and Gale Burnick.

The story is about a couple, John and Tandy, who choose to stay behind on Earth even though they know the sun is going to explode.  It mentions that years before millions of people had left on huge spaceships. The couple has 14 year old son named Brett and his friend Diane comes over and watches TV.  It also mentions that New York, Los Angeles, Miami and San Francisco are underwater because the ice caps have melted.  That night John touches the wall and notices that it is hot enough to burn.

The last lines of the story are:

> John rose and looked out the window.  The night sky was turning yellow. The sun had begun to explode. He turned to Tandy and kissed her lightly. The great wind from the sun blew death across the land.

[image: book cover - grey spaceship passing near a red planet]

The book is aimed at young readers and there are several pages with large pictures.  One of a couple standing outside and looking at a huge sun in the sky, one of a women fixing her hair in a mirror, and one of Brett and Diane watching tv.

The other stories in the book are :

- *The Disappearing Planet*

  This story is about two scientists who discover a giant flashing light beyond the orbit of Pluto that they think is a new planet.  They  go investigate and discover it is a giant spaceship and the flashing was a distress message.  As they try to leave the ship blows up and kills them.
- *Small Planet*

  This story is about a couple that crash lands on a planet.  Most of their food is destroyed but there are bushes with edible berries.  They hear strange squeaky noises and find tiny 8 inch tall humans.  Eventually the realize the berries are making them shrink.
- *The Secrets of Venus*

  This story is about the first two people to land on Venus.  The planet is supposed to be a barren desert, but they see something green from orbit like a long green snake.  They land and investigate.  When they do glass balls grow off of the snake like thing and form into copies of the two men and kill them.
- *The Last Martian*

  In this story everyone is fleeing the planet Mars because the air is running out, but one boy named Paul stays behind.
- *Gumdrop Planet*

  A ship lands on a planet and starts sinking so they can't take off again.  A crewmember goes to investigate but also starts sinking.  They eventually discover the planet is made of sugar and they can dump water on it to dissolve it and escape.
- *Between Planets*

  A ship is adrift in space,  eventually a huge ship with 8 armed octopus aliens save them.
- *Third Planet from the Sun*

  Two people are scouting alien planets for the U.N. They find one that is earthlike.  They land and setup a transmitter to communicate with earth.  There are strange beasts including a giraffe like creature but they seem friendly.  The next morning the transmitter has been broken into pieces.  The night after that one of the men goes missing.  Eventually we discover that the giraffe like creature did it.  It has two heads and shoots green beams out of its eyes, and puts the two men into a cage.

Comment: I found digitized copy on the Open Library website that is available to borrow if you want to check if its the right one.

Comment: Thank you... I really think this was it. When I was younger and read that last page it hit me really hard. The picture of the sun in the book looks very familiar so I think this might be it. Thank you. 

And thank you for reminding me about the Open Library. Turns out I had an account and that is going to be a lot of fun roaming through.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not this one, but I'll put it out there all the same:  is it possibly **Larry Niven's 1971 short story *Inconstant Moon***?

Most of this story takes place at night;  it is narrated by a man living in Los Angeles.  During the story, the man notices that the moon is unusually bright.  He reasons that it is due to a solar cataclysm, and that the day side of the Earth has already been destroyed.  Presuming this to be the last night of his life, he meets up with his girlfriend without telling her what is happening, though she works it out independently.

In the end,

> the cataclysm does not destroy the night side of the Earth, merely causing catastrophic flooding and extreme weather there.  The story ends the next morning, with the couple stranded in the girlfriend's apartment, wondering what the future will hold.

The time-frame fits, and the story has some similar elements (last night on Earth due to solar catastrophe, unusual weather, prominent romantic subplot).  The story was also well-regarded at the time, winning a Hugo award and being included in [many anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41283).  However, it doesn't exactly fit the description given by the OP;  in particular, the Sun explodes "off-screen" and before the story starts.

Comment: i think if la and ny are under water, the future will be bleak.